# Setting the Background Color of an Individual JTable Cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I know this question has been asked two or three times. I've viewed those threads and have not been able to reach a solution.

I'm simply trying to create a checkerboard pattern in a JTable. I have my own renderer that I've assigned to the cells as shown here: [jtable cellrenderer changes backgroundcolor of cells while running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14563799/jtable-cellrenderer-changes-backgroundcolor-of-cells-while-running)

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new CustomRenderer());
```

In my own code, I have the following:

```
public void initGUI(){
    //allocate the components
    frame = new JFrame();
    gamePanel = new JPanel();
    gameBoard = new BoardTable(){
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column){
            return false;
        }
    };

    //adjust the chessboard's look
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        gameBoard.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setMinWidth(SQUARE_CELL);
        gameBoard.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setPreferredWidth(SQUARE_CELL);
        gameBoard.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setMaxWidth(SQUARE_CELL);
        gameBoard.getColumnModel().getColumn(i).setCellRenderer(customRender);
    }
    gameBoard.setRowHeight(SQUARE_CELL);
    gameBoard.setFont(new Font(Font.SERIF, Font.PLAIN, 30));

    //adjust the panel's look
    gamePanel.setBackground(new Color(112, 128, 144));

    //put the pieces on the board
    updateBoard();

    //fit everything together
    gamePanel.add(gameBoard);
    frame.add(gamePanel);

    frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

My custom renderer is as follows:

```
public class BoardCellRenderer extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

    setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);

    if(row == 7)
        setBackground(new Color(100, 100, 100));

    if(hasFocus)
        setBorder(new MatteBorder(2, 2, 2, 2, Color.RED));

    return this;
}
```

When I run this code, the entire table is set to a dark gray. The `hasFocus` portion works flawlessly, but for some reason whenever I try to set the background for a single cell, it sets it for the entire table. How can I change the background for a specific cell using the `row` and `column` parameters?

Comment: This has indeed been asked thousands of times... You failed to read the documentation on [`DefaultTableCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableCellRenderer.html). If after reading you've seen the light... great. If not, add a comment telling you haven't.

Comment: Anticipating your comment, read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35686371/243373) on a similar problem.

Comment: Yep. I see it now. It's all coming back to me. I haven't played with Swing in a while, but I now remember that, when drawing simple shapes, I had to specify the color before each new shape, or specify it back to white. Thank you so much for your help.